# Assign groups based on other column's condition

Tags: python, dataframe

the current dataframe looks like:

```
id  col_1

0   3   1
1   3   2
2   3   3
3   3   4
4   1   1
5   1   2
6   1   3
7   2   1
8   2   2
9   3   1
10  3   2
11  3   3
12  4   1
```

I want to create a new column names `col_new`, which assign them to new groups.
It would look like this:

```
id  col_1   col_new
0   3   1   group1
1   3   2   group1
2   3   3   group1
3   3   4   group1
4   1   1   group2
5   1   2   group2
6   1   3   group2
7   2   1   group3
8   2   2   group3
9   3   1   group4
10  3   2   group4
11  3   3   group4
12  4   1   group5
```

Considering repeated values in id columns, just simply `groupby('id')` does not work. How can I assign these new groups?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Don't add data as images, instead, add them as text and use the appropriate [formatting](/help/formatting). Also, do not spam tags. Read their description, e.g. for [tag:python-3.x]: "DO NOT USE UNLESS YOUR QUESTION IS FOR PYTHON 3 ONLY. Always use alongside the standard [python] tag. " Or [tag:group-by] being for an SQL command. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to familiarise yourself with the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pluck the values of `'col_1'` with `shifted` values in the next step. Then set the value type to int, where they are true it will be 1, otherwise 0. Calculate the `cumulative sum` and convert the values to `strings`, add `'group'` to it.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
                   'col_1': [3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4]})


df['col_new'] = 'group' + (df['col_1']!=df['col_1'].shift()).astype(int).cumsum().astype(str)

print(df)
```

Output

```
    id  col_1 col_new
0    0      3  group1
1    1      3  group1
2    2      3  group1
3    3      3  group1
4    4      1  group2
5    5      1  group2
6    6      1  group2
7    7      2  group3
8    8      2  group3
9    9      3  group4
10  10      3  group4
11  11      3  group4
12  12      4  group5
```

Comment: Thank you. The result that I tested your code is:                                                    
 id  col_1  col_new
0    0      3   group1
1    1      3   group2
2    2      3   group3
3    3      3   group3
4    4      1   group4
5    5      1   group4
6    6      1   group5
7    7      2   group6
8    8      2   group7
9    9      3   group8
10  10      3   group9
11  11      3  group10
12  12      4  group11

Comment: What do you have in the first row of column col_1. Is it 3 1 or 3 (like mine)?

Comment: The first item of  column col_1 is 3.

Comment: but the line looks like this: 3 1. Right? Write here what will print: print(df.loc[0, 'col_1'])

Comment: mmmm, weird. This time it works fine. :-)

Comment: If the answer helps, then vote for the checkbox that is below the upper and lower triangle)

Comment: Still, show the entire first row of the col_1 column.